# Angularjs isolates scope directive with ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope, angularjs-ng-repeat

I'm trying to use directive on ng-repeat items each with an isolate scope but it isn't working.  I'm looping through each item and coloring it red with the inboxuser-select directive. However, when I put the directive on, it doesn't show any of my scope values.  What is the issue here?  Thanks

html file

```
   <li class="inbox-chatter"  data-ng-    
        repeat="inboxuser in inboxusers">
        <p inboxuser-select selected={{inboxuser}}">{{inboxuser}}</p>
       </li>
```

directive.js

```
.directive('inboxuserSelect', function() {
return {
    restrict: 'A',
    scope: {
        selected: "@"
    },
    link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
   scope.selected.css('color','red');
    }

}
 });
```

Comment: What is `inboxuser`. If it s a JS object how can you use `css` method

Comment: I simplified the function for display purposes. assume inboxuser is a string

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that once you set an isolate scope on the directive then the whole DOM element has that isolate scope.  So the `inboxuser` from your `ng-repeat` is no longer in scope when data binding occurs (it's on the parent scope).

One option is to set `scope` to true instead of using an isolate scope so you'll inherit everything from the parent scope.

Or you can stick with an isolate scope, but pass `inboxuser` in to the directive and display it using a template.  Since you're already passing `inboxuser` in to the directive's scope through `selected` it'd be easy to just add this to your directive:

```
   template: '{{selected}}',
```

Also, by the way, you're missing a quote on your `<p>`.  So this might work better for you (note I also removed `{{inboxuser}}` from within the `<p>` assuming you'll be using the template to display that instead):

```
  <p inboxuser-select selected="{{inboxuser}}"></p>
```

Answer (score 0):

To be honest, I don't understand what you really need to do but I have a feeling that this design will not get you there.

However, I fixed your example just for the purposes of explaining how things work.

You can see it live [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/O5HbkDmNHPhtsNEqvqWQ?p=preview).

So... when you write:

```
scope: {
    selected: "@"
}
```

you are actually saying that my isolated scope will hold a single property named `selected` which will be of type `string` and will contain whatever `{{inboxuser}}` evaluates to. And not only this, whenever `inboxuser` changes in the outter scope, `selected` will also change in the inner, isolated scope. This is how `'@'` binding works.

Whatever you put nested in `<p inboxuser-select selected="{{inboxuser}}"></p>`, is binded to that isolated scope, which does not have an `inboxuser` property. So, it has to change to:

```
<p inboxuser-select selected="{{inboxuser}}">{{selected}}</p>
```

Finally, `scope.selected.css('color','red');` should be changed to:

```
element.css('color','red');
```

The `element` argument in link function is the DOM element where the directive instance is applied. `scope.selected` is just a string.

I suggest you rething your overall design. If you need help, feel free to ask.

If it helps you, you can use [AngScope](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/angscope-simple-angularjs-s/), a tiny firebug extention i've written. It's just a quick way to inspect `$scope` instances associated to DOM elements inside firebug's DOM inspector.

Comment: You are right I was going about the wrong design.  What i was trying to achieve was clicking an element nested in a ngrepeat then making it highlight.  When I click another element, that one would un-highlight and the next one highlights.  Here is where I found the answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19852722/angularjs-directive-clicking-elements

Comment: Yeah, I saw this question, too. Try not to post semi-working code that makes no sense to anyone. Be clear about your use-case and always create a plunker for other guys to work on.